# Android: BitmapDrawable.Draw(Canvas) Doesn't seem to work

Tags: android, bitmap, draw

I am trying to tile a 20x20 background onto my Custom View but for some reason I am unable too.

```
    BitmapDrawable background;
    background = new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.back));
    background.setTileModeXY(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
    background.draw(canvas);
```

Does anyone have an idea why it isn't working?

Answer (score 6):

Don't set the bounds to the size of the tile: set them to the total area to be tiled. In your case:

```
background.setBounds(0, 0, myView.getWidth(), myView.getHeight());
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to give your drawable bounds. You need to call drawable.setBounds() at least once before drawing it.

Comment: What bounds should I set if I want the image to be tiled all over the screen though? Setting to (0, 0, 20, 20) gives me the same problem, it doesn't appear.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have fixed this problem with the following code

```
//background
    Bitmap _back_bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.background); 
    BitmapDrawable backTiled = new BitmapDrawable(_back_bmp);
    backTiled.setTileModeXY(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
    backTiled.setBounds(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
    this.back_bmp = backTiled.getTileModeX();
    this.setBackgroundDrawable(backTiled);
```

But I have my own problem now. Nothing can be drawn to the canvas?